# What test do I run to check multi-collinearity for not normal data?

Tags: multicollinearity

I have 7 study subjects which I have grouped in 3 combinations ID1, ID2 and ID3.

I have 15 behaviours which I have grouped into 5 combinations (Bgroup1, Bgroup2 etc..)

[image: Bgroups and IDgroups with the amount of levels]

Within each level, there are different amounts of data.

I want to know which combination of Bgroup and ID best explains the data set. I don't know which correlation tests to run and how to do this in R (perhaps log linear/GLMMS's/basic colinearity tests?). Once I have found the best model to describe the data set, I can further compare behaviour to other variables that I have.

Example Question 1): When split into ID group 1, which Bgroup best explains the data set? If Bgroup 5 or 6 best explains, then it is worth conflating the behavioural categories.

Example Question 2): Is it possible to assess whether ID group 1,2 or 3 is better to use for behavioural analysis?

Problems I've encountered so far:

-*Error in table(df.Bgroup1$ID1, df.Bgroup1$ID2, df.Bgroup1$ID3) :
all arguments must have the same length.*

- Data is not-normally distributed for example:
  Count <-   *Table (df.Bgroup2$ID2):

  1 ,   2 ,  3  ,  4 ,   6  ,  7  ,  8    ,9

1759 , 106  ,207  , 62  , 14  ,  2  , 10 ,   9

Is this possible? I am a newby to R, so apologies if I haven't included enough information.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Could you post a snippet of your actual data frame (I assume you have one in which each level is represented by either a row or a column), and could you explain what you mean by "explaining the data set"? What are you trying to find out? What is your dependent variable and what are the independent variables? Or are you trying to reduce the data into smaller number of dimensions? What does "behavioral analysis" mean here?

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment and help! 
Behaviour is dependant and ID group is independant (I hypothesize that ID group will influence behaviour group- but I want to know which ones are most influenced by each grouping). 

I want to find out:
1) which behaviour group (where I conflated all 15 levels into smaller groups) can be used, rather than using the original levels as 15 is too much. 
2) which ID groups show the best linearity within the behaviour groups?

I have 5077 rows of data. I wanted to conflate because some observations are <10 and some are >1000. 

Snippet added

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I'm afraid I still don't quite understand your design and I hope more experienced posters here will help you. However, if you essentially have 2 categorical variables (behavioral group and id), a typical way of evaluating their connections is either logistic (/multinomial) regression or a chi-square test based on contingency tables.